# cuda glib error

Tags: cuda

Below is cuda code I would expect to work. I'm getting a "double free or corruption" error. After much debugging, I've identified the offending line to be "cudaMemcpy(out, out_device...). I'm completely dumbfounded as to why this error persists. Any help would be appreciated.
ComplexFloat is typedef-ed as float2.

```
void covariance2(float alpha, complex float* in, complex float* out, int dims[5])
{
    int x = dims[0];
    int y = dims[1];
    int z = dims[2];
    int N = dims[3];
    int M = dims[4];

    ComplexFloat* in_device;
    ComplexFloat* out_device;
    int siz = x*y*z*N*(N+1)/2;
    assert(cudaMalloc(&in_device, sizeof(ComplexFloat)*x*y*z*N*M) == cudaSuccess);
    assert(cudaMalloc(&out_device, sizeof(ComplexFloat)*siz) == cudaSuccess);
    assert(cudaMemcpy(in_device, in, sizeof(ComplexFloat)*x*y*z*N*M, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) == cudaSuccess);
    dim3 numBlocks(x,y,z);
    dim3 numThreads(1);
    size_t sharedMem = N*M + N*(N+1)/2;

    cudaMemcpy(out, out_device, sizeof(ComplexFloat)*siz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(in_device);
    cudaFree(out_device);
}

int main()
    {
    int xxx = 2;
    int yyy = 2;
    int zzz = 1;
    int MMM = 7;
    int NNN = 3;
    int dims[5] = { xxx, yyy, zzz, MMM, NNN };
    float alpha = 5.;
    complex float a = 1.314 + 5.42*_Complex_I;
    complex float* in = (complex float*) malloc(sizeof(complex float)*NNN*MMM*xxx*yyy*zzz);
    for (int i = 0; i < xxx*yyy*zzz*MMM*NNN; i++)
        in[i] = a*pow(i,2);
    complex float* out = (complex float*) malloc(sizeof(complex float)*xxx*yyy*zzz*NNN*(NNN+1)/2);
    assert(out);
    covariance2(alpha, in, out, dims);
    for (int i = 0; i < NNN*(NNN+1)/2; i++)
        printf("i = %d, real = %f, imag = %f\n", i, __real__(out[i]), __imag__(out[i]));
    free(out);
    }
```

Comment: Do you deliberately not have a kernal call in there? Currently, you are copying something into memory, and then copying other stuff out of memory. That other stuff will be junk, unless you do something to it.
And you should definitely check that sizeof(ComplexFloat) == sizeof(complex float).

One more thing: why would you want multiple blocks with only one active thread in them each? You are only going to get a maximum performance of 1/32 of what is possible doing it that way - the GPU processes in warps of 32 threads, regardless of how many you are actually using.

Comment: i did have a kernel call, I removed it just for the sake of the question. Once this works, I will add more threads. sizeof(complex float) == sizeof(float2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `covariance2` function you have:

```
int N = dims[3];
int M = dims[4];
```

but inside your `main()` you have:

```
int dims[5] = { xxx, yyy, zzz, MMM, NNN };
```

Note that M is a parameter preceding N in `dims[]`

Since your malloc (of `out`) and cudaMalloc (of `out_device`) depend on N, you are using two different values for N (3 and 7) to compute the sizes.  This means `out` and `out_device` are not the same size, which I don't think was your intent.  Since (size of) `out` was computed with N of 3, and (size of) `out_device` was computed with N of 7, you are trying to cudaMemcpy a larger data structure onto a smaller one.  The fix is presumably something like this in covariance2:

```
int M = dims[3];
int N = dims[4];
```

Comment: It's the sly things like this that keep you on your toes :P